# How can I overwrite html file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, overwrite

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(klasoradi + htmlname + ".html")))
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(klasoradi + htmlname + ".html"), htmltext);
}
```

I'm using this code for creating and saving my html file. But I can't overwrite the file.

Can you please help me fix this situation ?

Comment: Do you get an **error** when trying to overwrite? If so: please **post** the complete and exact error message!

Comment: Just remove your if statement.

Comment: Read your code. Your if statement checks if the file does NOT exist, and if it does, to write to it. Did you even bother to debug this? If you had, you'd have noticed your if statement never evaluates to true.

Comment: @DanielCook i removed if.. In the first test worked. Creted the file and saved it. But when i do this again i get this error : This process using by another proccess

Comment: @Seration Different issue. You can't overwrite a file that is already open for editing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `WriteAllText(string,string)` will overwrite a file. So, all you need to do is remove your initial if statement and it will either create the file or overwrite it.

Comment: i removed if.. In the first test worked. Creted the file and saved it. But when i do this again i get this error : This process using by another proccess